# UITextField segue to TableViewController not working

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to perform segue from a text field on a View Controller to a Table View Controller that is set up to allow the user to search for an item from a database and bring that item back to the text field on the View Controller.  I am trying to use the following programming for the segue but when you click on the text field the keyboard comes up and no segue occurs.

```
import UIKit

class MainVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var color: UITextField!

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    performSegueWithIdentifier("selectColor", sender: self)
}
```

I thought that textFieldDidBeginEditing was supposed to become the first responder so that the segue would occur as opposed to the keyboard appearing.

Comment: Do you set the controller as the text field's delegate?

Comment: Thank you.  Classic new programmer mistake. The segue now functions but...  the tableview opens twice.  Any idea what causes that to happen?